# Should the aircraft logbook be with the aircraft, or should it be on the ground?

Tags: anac-regulations

Should an aircraft logbook stay inside of the airplane, or on the ground with maintenance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is depending on which country the airplane is registered in, as the requirement to carry the logbook can be implemented per country, e.g. Germany requires the logbook to be carried onboard the airplane.<sub>[LuftBO §30 Abs. 5]</sub>

Comment: In that case, how do they audit the logbook after a crash?

Comment: There must be a copy, or something in the ground. But what about the US, they require the logbook onboard?

Comment: @abelenky If the original logbook is destroyed, information can also be taken from maintenance logs, older logbooks (need to be kept for 2 years) and other suitable documentation, where hours and cycles can be deducted from.

Answer (score 11):

As an aircraft owner in the US I never kept a logbook in the aircraft.  I do this for two reasons:

1. Someone from the FAA can come up and ask to the see the logbook when I am on my way someplace.  They can then tie me up for hours while they peruse the logs.  And if they find something they do not like ground the aircraft until we get the issue resolve.  That would strand me at some airport.  If the logbook is at home I can tell them to have their local office make an appointment.
2. If the log books are in the aircraft they can be stolen when the aircraft is parked.  Since the log books are a history of troubles repaired on the plane, service performed, etc, they are the authoritative history of the plane's health.  As such the log books represent a significant portion of the value of an aircraft (say 10-15%).

Comment: I'd daresay that the reason that the aviation agency of the country can request the aircraft logbook is the reason why some countries require it to be carried around. No FAA regulation regarding the logbook?

Comment: @SentryRaven Under US regulations you are required to produce the aircraft logbooks if the FAA (or other authorized agency) requests them, but you are not required to carry them in the aircraft.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you carry around a copy of the last page or anything to prove the plane is airworthy, e.g. not exceeding TBO?

Comment: @SentryRaven there's no reason to -- the FAA isn't looking to ground an airplane that isn't obviously airworthy with immediacy; they're content to require you to produce the logs in time rather than on the spot. That said, exceeding TBO is not an airworthy issue for all aircraft.

Comment: @Sentry Raven - I never carried anything, but I have heard about other owners carrying photocopies of certain pages.  Usually things like completion of an STC (Supplemental Type Certificate) that allowed the aircraft to burn car gas instead of aviation 100LL.

Comment: A friend carries an electronic copy of his maintenance log book so that should he need maintenance far from home, the A&P at the remote location can view what has been done in the past.  Just like the pilot's log book, there is no requirement to carry it.  Should you need to show either log to the FAA, producing it in a reasonable amount of time (i.e., go home and bring it to the FSDO next week) is entirely acceptable.

Comment: I find this highly suspicious. Were I an inspector I'd ground you on suspicion of irregularities until the logs can be produced...

Comment: In the unlikely event that there is an accident that destroys the aircraft, reviewing the logs might help the investigators determine the cause of the crash. And, in the US at least, the insurance company is going to want to see the logbooks to make sure the aircraft is airworthy before they pay out. e.g. If the aircraft is out of annual or has not complied with all of the ADs, my insurance policy states that the company will not cover any damages.

Comment: @jwenting, I'm curious, what country do you live in?

Comment: @MichaelHall Netherlands.